# Id attribute is null for entity JPA Buddy

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, jpa-buddy

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Work_Order")
public class WorkOrder {

  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue 
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "transaction_group_id")
  private TransactionGroup transactionGroup;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "Transaction_Group")
public class TransactionGroup {

  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue 
  private long id;

  @TenantId
  @Column(name = "tenant_id", nullable = false)
  private String tenantId;

  @Column(name = "timestamp", nullable = false)
  private long timestamp;

  @ManyToOne
  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getTenantId() {
    return tenantId;
  }

  public long getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
  }
}
```

Why JPA Buddy gives me the following error when i try to generate a db snapshot?

I have an ID in the TransactionGroup entity.

[image: exception]

Also, i have tried to use Long instead of long for the ID. However, it didn’t give any results.

Comment: It should definitely be a `Long`. How are the IDs generated? Also, what is `@TenantId`?

Comment: Why should it be Long? It can be anything, even UUID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do – is to remove the @ManyToOne annotation from your getId() method.

By the way, I've just checked that Hibernate doesn't complain about such annotations over methods, so we'll try to do the same in the next JPA Buddy releases. Here you can track the status of this task: https://issues.jpa-buddy.com/issue/JPAB-2246.